# Not enough main memory to complete the sort - with CEMU

Tags: batch-file

...even though I have 4gb free out of 8gb ram. Here's the code

```
for /f "delims=" %%e in ('dir e:\source /a:d /b /s ^| sort /r') do (
    rd "%%e" 2>nul && if defined verbal echo deleted empty directory %%~ne
)
```

This is a part of a script that runs on an infinite loop every 120 seconds. Not sure if that matters.

edit: **Just noticed that this only happens when [CEMU](http://cemu.info/) emulator is open.**

Comment: How big is your directory tree listing? I.e. `dir e:\source /ad /b /s >e:\tmp.tmp && dir e:\tmp.tmp && del e:\tmp.tmp` - what does it print?

Comment: 114 folders currently

Comment: I was expecting an answer in kilobytes, megabytes or even gigabytes (size of directory listing). The names of 114 folders probably would take only a few tens of kilobytes of memory in the sort process. There must be something else going on. Do you have lots of junctions or symbolic links to parent/grandparent directories? These would cause the directory listing to get very large. That's why I asked for the size of the directory listing, not the number of folders.

Comment: Got it. 9584 bytes. No links or junctions here.

Comment: The `sort` utility has a `/m` option to specify the maximum memory to use. This option must be a minimum of 160 kilobytes (type `sort /?`). The directory listing is less than 10 kilobytes and therefore easily fits in memory many times over. There has to be something strange going on.

Comment: Why are you bothering to sort directories you're going to be deleting anyway?  Why not just `for /R "E:\source" /D %%I in (*) do rd etc.`?  Seems that would be the most efficient solution.  I get that using `sort /r` allows you to delete recursively where entire branches of directories contain no files, but it seems to me the 120 second infinite loop would accomplish the same recursion sooner or later.  Alternatively, you could use a `goto` loop until no more directories have been deleted.

Comment: True, that's a solution. Thanks.